# ssl connection between two servers by API using php

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I having two server, these two server connect by the API using curl
but my client asking need to connect by server SSL connection.
But i dont have idea about this process

```
 $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
    'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Bter PHP bot; '.php_uname('a').'; PHP/'.phpversion().')'
    );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://server2/index.php/api/'.$path);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

// run the query
$res = curl_exec($ch);
```

how can i make ssl connect between server anyone please help to me

thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if change it to `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://server2/index.php/api/'.$path);`?

Comment: I got the correct response from the server 2 if i give the correct url on the curl url but our client said "need to connect through SSL". So please guide how make the ssl connect. if i am wrong please correct me